# error loading java classes in crate

Tags: debian, upgrade, apt, crate

I just updated crate via debian apt from 1.1.1. to 1.1.3. Starting crate I get following error:

```
[2017-05-29 16:59:59,858][ERROR][bootstrap                ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: io.crate.plugin.PluginLoaderPlugin
jar1: /usr/share/crate/lib/crate-app-1.1.3.jar
jar2: /usr/share/crate/lib/crate-app-1.1.1.jar
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:285)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:186)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:87)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:175)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:300)
        at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:50)
```

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a packaging error - or something else went wrong during the upgrade. Which Debian version are you using?

As a workaround you can solve the error by manually deleting `/usr/share/crate/lib/crate-app-1.1.1.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed crate, deleted the (old) jars and reinstalled it. Now it works.